# Почему функция QUOTE() в MySQL не экранирует бекслеш?

Tags: mysql

Почему QUOTE() не экранирует \, хотя нормально экранирует одиночную кавычку?

При запросе
`SELECT QUOTE("'");`
результат получается с экранированием:
`'\''`.

А вот при запросе `SELECT QUOTE("\");` сервер считает, что вторая двойная кавычка заэкранирована и предлагает завершить запрос еще одной двойной кавычкой.

В документации утверждается, что

> The string is returned enclosed by single quotation marks and with
>   each instance of backslash (\), single quote ('), ASCII NUL, and
>   Control+Z preceded by a backslash.

Comment: потому что косую черту обрабатывает парсер запроса еще до того как начать его выполнять и до вызова каких либо функций дело не доходит

Comment: @Mike очевидно, что это происходит. однако сама qoute и задумана, чтобы обратную косую предварять подобной. почему и возник вопрос о непонятном в таком случае для меня поведении функции.

Comment: она задумана что бы выполнить это для некой строки данных полученной на вход, полученную например из колонки базы данных. И косую черту она отлично экранирует. сравните результат `select '\\', QUOTE('\\')`. Но вы передаете ей на вход не имя какой нибудь колонки, а строковый литерал. А _любой_ строковый литерал вы сами должны оформить подобающим образом, в том числе заэкранировать обратную косую или например такие же кавычки в которых строка, иначе как синтаксическому анализатору понять что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @Mike спасибо, теперь ситуация для меня прояснилась

Comment: @Mike в заблуждение ввело поведение функции при вызове `select QUOTE("'"), QUOTE("\'")`. Что дает одинаковый результат: `'\''`. В первом случае одиночную кавычку ставит сама функция, во втором прописана вручную.

Comment: Она в обоих случаях прописана вручную. в функцию в обоих случаях как параметр попадает строка из одной кавычки. обратная косая пропадает на стадии лексического анализа